# Usage of chain rule when derivative is zero

Tags: calculus

Suppose that $f(a,b)$. And $a = g(t, d_i...)$ and $b = t$.

Also suppose that $da/dt = 0 = da/db$. In this case, is it safe to say that $df/dt = df/db = 0$?

Comment: If $da/dt=0$ then it means that $a$ has no dependency on t and in the partial differentiation, can be treated as constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have $\phi(t) = f(g(t), t)$, so $\frac{d \phi(t)}{dt} = \frac{\partial f(g(t), t)}{da}\frac{\partial g(t)}{\partial t}+ \frac{\partial f(g(t), t)}{db}$. Since $\frac{\partial g(t)}{\partial t} = 0$, you have $\frac{d \phi(t)}{dt} =\frac{\partial f(g(t), t)}{db}$.